# How to pass function as Expression in Linq Select statement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I have two methods, which are returning min and max dates from table:

```
private static DateTime? GetNewestDateFromStatistics(IDbConnection db)
{
        return db.Single<DateTime?>(db.From<Statistic>()
                                             .Select(e => Sql.Max(e.DateTimeCest));
}

private static DateTime? GetOldestDateFromStatistics(IDbConnection db)
{
        return db.Single<DateTime?>(db.From<Statistic>()
                                             .Select(e => Sql.Min(e.DateTimeCest));
}
```

What I would like is to have one method and dynamically pass Sql.Min or Sql.Max into Select, so my Method will have additional parameter. This is how I tried:

```
Expression<Func<Statistic, DateTime>> expMin = i => Sql.Min(i.DateTimeCest);

private static DateTime? GetDateFromStatistics(IDbConnection db, 
                                                 Expression<Func<Statistic, DateTime>> exp)
{
   return db.Single<DateTime?>(db.From<Statistic>()
                                  .Select(e => exp.Compile().Invoke(e)));
}
```

And would call my method:

```
GetDateFromStatistics(db, expMin);
```

I got an error

> 'variable of type 'Statistic' referenced from scope '', but it is not
>   defined'

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of Statistic, can u try to keep T alone and try like Expression<Func<T, DateTime>>

Comment: Why do you need it to be "Expression..." and not "Func<T, DateTime> exp", and then just call "exp(e)"?

Comment: with T, I get compile error, so I need to pass `Statistic` . With passing `Func<Statistic, DateTime> exp` to function and calling in `Select(e => exp.Invoke(e))`, I get : `variable 'e' of type 'Statistic' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve. The type of the `exp` argument matches exactly the signature of the `Queryable.Select`, so it can be used directly, e.g. `Select(exp)`

Comment: @IvanStoev If I use it directly, than I get `cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Statistic, System.DateTime>>' to 'string'`

Comment: Then "Linq Select statement" from the post title is incorrect - looks like you are using some *non standard* methods with the same name as the LINQ ones. Please update the post with the signature of the target `Select` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
private static DateTime? GetDateFromStatistics(IDbConnection db, 
                                               Expression<Func<Statistic, DateTime>> exp)
{
   return db.Single<DateTime?>(db.From<Statistic>()
                                 .Select(exp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need `Expression` here at all, this seems to work out fine:

```
Func<Statistic, DateTime> expMin = i => Sql.Min(i.DateTimeCest);
...
private static DateTime? GetDateFromStatistics(IDbConnection db, 
                                                 Func<Statistic, DateTime> exp)
{
   return db.Single<DateTime?>(db.From<Statistic>().Select(exp));
}
...
GetDateFromStatistics(db, expMin);
```

Comment: Can not Func, because this is a signature of the Select `public virtual SqlExpression<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, object>> fields);`